# performance issues with MYISAM

Tags: mysql, database, myisam

folks

i need to generate a report from the  table A  ( about 60 million records and myisam storage engine). The table A is dumped with cdr files every 15 minutes.

I would like to generate a report based on (date to) and (date from)

couple of scenarios that i tried are as below

1) i tried to create a temporary table B ( using create table B Engine=Myisam select a,c,d from table A)

in the processlist , the Table A is locked if the table A is being dumped with cdr records. And will remain locked.

if there are no inserts of cdr records in Table A, then the temporary table B is created in about 1 minutes.

is there any way i can create temporary table B  when the files are being dumped in table A.

2) i tried to create a temporary table B ( using create table B select a.c.d from table A)

in this case , table b that is created INNODB engine and will take lot of space

3) Just need info if i create temporary b engine=Memory, will it have any performance issues or not.

I m attaching my.cnf as below

```
# Example MySQL config file for very large systems.
#
# This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer_size = 3G
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 1024
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 1024M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4G
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 256M
query_cache_limit = 256M

max_connections = 100   
max_heap_table_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 1024M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 3G
slow_query_log



# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 8

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin
#
# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 100M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 3G
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 1024M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

dhairya

Comment: If you are looking "behind" on details, i.e. you don't care about the latest information, because data is inserted NOW, but you are looking at yesterday's results, you can have MySQL NOT lock data - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: nrathaus , we still have the issue i checked the site. but not able to get the solution. what we should change in the query or in the my.cnf file so that tables are not locked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in one MySQL session):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
READ UNCOMMITTED;

<place here the blocking query>
```

You should see that the SQL has't blocked the INSERT